# Problem when using Pandas json_normalize to flatten the nested JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, json-normalize

I have a JSON file with the following structure (below is the content of `retweets[:2]`):

```
[{'lang': 'en',
  'author_id': '1076979440372965377',
  'reply_settings': 'everyone',
  'entities': {'mentions': [{'start': 3,
     'end': 17,
     'username': 'Terry81987010',
     'url': '',
     'location': 'Florida',
     'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 29,
         'end': 32,
         'tag': '2A'}]}},
     'created_at': '2019-02-01T23:01:11.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 520,
      'following_count': 567,
      'tweet_count': 34376,
      'listed_count': 1},
     'name': "Terry's Take",
     'verified': False,
     'id': '1091471553437593605',
     'description': 'Less government more Freedom #2A is a constitutional right. Trump2020, common sense rules, God bless America! Vet 82nd Airborne F/A, proud Republican',
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289626661911134208/WfztLkr1_normal.jpg'},
    {'start': 19,
     'end': 32,
     'username': 'DineshDSouza',
     'location': 'United States',
     'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'start': 0,
         'end': 23,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]},
      'description': {'urls': [{'start': 80,
         'end': 103,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]}},
     'created_at': '2009-11-22T22:32:41.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 1748832,
      'following_count': 5355,
      'tweet_count': 65674,
      'listed_count': 6966},
     'name': "Dinesh D'Souza",
     'verified': True,
     'pinned_tweet_id': '1393309917239562241',
     'id': '91882544',
     'description': "I am an author, filmmaker, and host of the Dinesh D'Souza Podcast.\n\nSubscribe: ",
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890967538292711424/8puyFbiI_normal.jpg'}]},
  'conversation_id': '1253462541881106433',
  'created_at': '2020-04-23T23:15:32.000Z',
  'id': '1253462541881106433',
  'possibly_sensitive': False,
  'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'retweeted',
    'id': '1253052684489437184',
    'in_reply_to_user_id': '91882544',
    'attachments': {'media_keys': ['3_1253052312144293888',
      '3_1253052620937277442'],
     'media': [{}, {}]},
    'entities': {'annotations': [{'start': 126,
       'end': 128,
       'probability': 0.514,
       'type': 'Organization',
       'normalized_text': 'CDC'},
      {'start': 145,
       'end': 146,
       'probability': 0.5139,
       'type': 'Place',
       'normalized_text': 'NY'}],
     'mentions': [{'start': 0,
       'end': 13,
       'username': 'DineshDSouza',
       'location': 'United States',
       'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'start': 0,
           'end': 23,
           'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
           'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]},
        'description': {'urls': [{'start': 80,
           'end': 103,
           'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
           'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]}},
       'created_at': '2009-11-22T22:32:41.000Z',
       'protected': False,
       'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 1748832,
        'following_count': 5355,
        'tweet_count': 65674,
        'listed_count': 6966},
       'name': "Dinesh D'Souza",
       'verified': True,
       'pinned_tweet_id': '1393309917239562241',
       'id': '91882544',
       'description': "I am an author, filmmaker, and host of the Dinesh D'Souza Podcast.\n\nSubscribe:  ",
       'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890967538292711424/8puyFbiI_normal.jpg'}],
     'urls': [{'start': 187,
       'end': 210,
       'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/Terry81987010/status/1253052684489437184/photo/1',
       'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/H4NpN5ZMkW'},
      {'start': 187,
       'end': 210,
       'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/Terry81987010/status/1253052684489437184/photo/1',
       'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/H4NpN5ZMkW'}]},
    'lang': 'en',
    'author_id': '1091471553437593605',
    'reply_settings': 'everyone',
    'conversation_id': '1253050942716551168',
    'created_at': '2020-04-22T20:06:55.000Z',
    'possibly_sensitive': False,
    'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1253050942716551168'}],
    'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 208,
     'reply_count': 57,
     'like_count': 402,
     'quote_count': 38},
    'source': 'Twitter Web App',
    'text': "@DineshDSouza Here's some proof of artificially inflating the cv deaths. Noone is dying of pneumonia anymore according to the CDC. And of course NY getting paid for each cv death $60,000",
    'context_annotations': [{'domain': {'id': '10',
       'name': 'Person',
       'description': 'Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela'},
      'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}},
     {'domain': {'id': '35',
       'name': 'Politician',
       'description': 'Politicians in the world, like Joe Biden'},
      'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}}],
    'author': {'url': '',
     'username': 'Terry81987010',
     'location': 'Florida',
     'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 29,
         'end': 32,
         'tag': '2A'}]}},
     'created_at': '2019-02-01T23:01:11.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 520,
      'following_count': 567,
      'tweet_count': 34376,
      'listed_count': 1},
     'name': "Terry's Take",
     'verified': False,
     'id': '1091471553437593605',
     'description': 'Less government more Freedom #2A is a constitutional right. Trump2020, common sense rules, God bless America! Vet 82nd Airborne F/A, proud Republican',
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289626661911134208/WfztLkr1_normal.jpg'},
    'in_reply_to_user': {'username': 'DineshDSouza',
     'location': 'United States',
     'entities': {'url': {'urls': [{'start': 0,
         'end': 23,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]},
      'description': {'urls': [{'start': 80,
         'end': 103,
         'expanded_url': 'https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-dinesh-dsouza-podcast/id1547827376',
         'display_url': 'podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the…'}]}},
     'created_at': '2009-11-22T22:32:41.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 1748832,
      'following_count': 5355,
      'tweet_count': 65674,
      'listed_count': 6966},
     'name': "Dinesh D'Souza",
     'verified': True,
     'pinned_tweet_id': '1393309917239562241',
     'id': '91882544',
     'description': "I am an author, filmmaker, and host of the Dinesh D'Souza Podcast.\n\nSubscribe:  ",
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/890967538292711424/8puyFbiI_normal.jpg'}}],
  'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 208,
   'reply_count': 0,
   'like_count': 0,
   'quote_count': 0},
  'source': 'Twitter for iPhone',
  'text': "RT @Terry81987010: @DineshDSouza Here's some proof of artificially inflating the cv deaths. Noone is dying of pneumonia anymore according t…",
  'context_annotations': [{'domain': {'id': '10',
     'name': 'Person',
     'description': 'Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela'},
    'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}},
   {'domain': {'id': '35',
     'name': 'Politician',
     'description': 'Politicians in the world, like Joe Biden'},
    'entity': {'id': '1138120064119369729', 'name': "Dinesh D'Souza"}}],
  'author': {'url': '',
   'username': 'set1952',
   'location': 'Etats-Unis',
   'created_at': '2018-12-23T23:14:42.000Z',
   'protected': False,
   'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 103,
    'following_count': 44,
    'tweet_count': 44803,
    'listed_count': 0},
   'name': 'SunSet1952',
   'verified': False,
   'id': '1076979440372965377',
   'description': '',
   'profile_image_url': 'https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_normal.png'},
  '__twarc': {'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?expansions=author_id%2Cin_reply_to_user_id%2Creferenced_tweets.id%2Creferenced_tweets.id.author_id%2Centities.mentions.username%2Cattachments.poll_ids%2Cattachments.media_keys%2Cgeo.place_id&user.fields=created_at%2Cdescription%2Centities%2Cid%2Clocation%2Cname%2Cpinned_tweet_id%2Cprofile_image_url%2Cprotected%2Cpublic_metrics%2Curl%2Cusername%2Cverified%2Cwithheld&tweet.fields=attachments%2Cauthor_id%2Ccontext_annotations%2Cconversation_id%2Ccreated_at%2Centities%2Cgeo%2Cid%2Cin_reply_to_user_id%2Clang%2Cpublic_metrics%2Ctext%2Cpossibly_sensitive%2Creferenced_tweets%2Creply_settings%2Csource%2Cwithheld&media.fields=duration_ms%2Cheight%2Cmedia_key%2Cpreview_image_url%2Ctype%2Curl%2Cwidth%2Cpublic_metrics&poll.fields=duration_minutes%2Cend_datetime%2Cid%2Coptions%2Cvoting_status&place.fields=contained_within%2Ccountry%2Ccountry_code%2Cfull_name%2Cgeo%2Cid%2Cname%2Cplace_type&max_results=500&query=retweets_of%3ATerry81987010&start_time=2020-03-09T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end_time=2020-04-24T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00',
   'version': '2.0.8',
   'retrieved_at': '2021-05-17T17:13:17+00:00'}},
 {'attachments': {'media_keys': ['3_1253366603061878792'],
   'media': [{'media_key': '3_1253366603061878792',
     'type': 'photo',
     'height': 1920,
     'width': 1080,
     'url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EWTaSOzXYAgBEqO.jpg'}]},
  'lang': 'en',
  'author_id': '157054921',
  'reply_settings': 'everyone',
  'entities': {'mentions': [{'start': 3,
     'end': 17,
     'username': 'Terry81987010',
     'url': '',
     'location': 'Florida',
     'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 29,
         'end': 32,
         'tag': '2A'}]}},
     'created_at': '2019-02-01T23:01:11.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 520,
      'following_count': 567,
      'tweet_count': 34376,
      'listed_count': 1},
     'name': "Terry's Take",
     'verified': False,
     'id': '1091471553437593605',
     'description': 'Less government more Freedom #2A is a constitutional right. Trump2020, common sense rules, God bless America! Vet 82nd Airborne F/A, proud Republican',
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289626661911134208/WfztLkr1_normal.jpg'},
    {'start': 19, 'end': 31, 'username': 'mitchellvii'}],
   'urls': [{'start': 60,
     'end': 83,
     'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/Terry81987010/status/1253366701112070147/photo/1',
     'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/mQLE5TZviE'}]},
  'conversation_id': '1253446311753453576',
  'created_at': '2020-04-23T22:11:03.000Z',
  'id': '1253446311753453576',
  'possibly_sensitive': False,
  'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'retweeted',
    'id': '1253366701112070147',
    'in_reply_to_user_id': '17980523',
    'attachments': {'media_keys': ['3_1253366603061878792'],
     'media': [{'media_key': '3_1253366603061878792',
       'type': 'photo',
       'height': 1920,
       'width': 1080,
       'url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EWTaSOzXYAgBEqO.jpg'}]},
    'lang': 'en',
    'author_id': '1091471553437593605',
    'reply_settings': 'everyone',
    'entities': {'mentions': [{'start': 0,
       'end': 12,
       'username': 'mitchellvii'}],
     'urls': [{'start': 41,
       'end': 64,
       'expanded_url': 'https://twitter.com/Terry81987010/status/1253366701112070147/photo/1',
       'display_url': 'pic.twitter.com/mQLE5TZviE'}]},
    'conversation_id': '1253364124416978951',
    'created_at': '2020-04-23T16:54:42.000Z',
    'possibly_sensitive': False,
    'referenced_tweets': [{'type': 'replied_to', 'id': '1253364124416978951'}],
    'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 4,
     'reply_count': 1,
     'like_count': 4,
     'quote_count': 0},
    'source': 'Twitter Web App',
    'text': '@mitchellvii Is it really a coincidence?',
    'context_annotations': [{'domain': {'id': '10',
       'name': 'Person',
       'description': 'Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela'},
      'entity': {'id': '1138048048972517376',
       'name': 'Bill Mitchell',
       'description': 'Professor'}}],
    'author': {'url': '',
     'username': 'Terry81987010',
     'location': 'Florida',
     'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 29,
         'end': 32,
         'tag': '2A'}]}},
     'created_at': '2019-02-01T23:01:11.000Z',
     'protected': False,
     'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 520,
      'following_count': 567,
      'tweet_count': 34376,
      'listed_count': 1},
     'name': "Terry's Take",
     'verified': False,
     'id': '1091471553437593605',
     'description': 'Less government more Freedom #2A is a constitutional right. Trump2020, common sense rules, God bless America! Vet 82nd Airborne F/A, proud Republican',
     'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1289626661911134208/WfztLkr1_normal.jpg'},
    'in_reply_to_user': {}}],
  'public_metrics': {'retweet_count': 4,
   'reply_count': 0,
   'like_count': 0,
   'quote_count': 0},
  'source': 'Twitter for iPhone',
  'text': 'RT @Terry81987010: @mitchellvii Is it really a coincidence?',
  'context_annotations': [{'domain': {'id': '10',
     'name': 'Person',
     'description': 'Named people in the world like Nelson Mandela'},
    'entity': {'id': '1138048048972517376',
     'name': 'Bill Mitchell',
     'description': 'Professor'}}],
  'author': {'url': '',
   'username': 'BillyBoysDaddy',
   'entities': {'description': {'hashtags': [{'start': 93,
       'end': 98,
       'tag': 'MAGA'}]}},
   'created_at': '2010-06-18T18:29:28.000Z',
   'protected': False,
   'public_metrics': {'followers_count': 10510,
    'following_count': 9001,
    'tweet_count': 444455,
    'listed_count': 171},
   'name': 'Sonlight ',
   'verified': False,
   'id': '157054921',
   'description': 'The way that it is ... is ... the way that it is ...... and it could not be otherwise ...... #MAGA',
   'profile_image_url': 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/3464880142/bb34db1c7344eca5bd8ce7196ff0e003_normal.jpeg'},
  '__twarc': {'url': 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all?expansions=author_id%2Cin_reply_to_user_id%2Creferenced_tweets.id%2Creferenced_tweets.id.author_id%2Centities.mentions.username%2Cattachments.poll_ids%2Cattachments.media_keys%2Cgeo.place_id&user.fields=created_at%2Cdescription%2Centities%2Cid%2Clocation%2Cname%2Cpinned_tweet_id%2Cprofile_image_url%2Cprotected%2Cpublic_metrics%2Curl%2Cusername%2Cverified%2Cwithheld&tweet.fields=attachments%2Cauthor_id%2Ccontext_annotations%2Cconversation_id%2Ccreated_at%2Centities%2Cgeo%2Cid%2Cin_reply_to_user_id%2Clang%2Cpublic_metrics%2Ctext%2Cpossibly_sensitive%2Creferenced_tweets%2Creply_settings%2Csource%2Cwithheld&media.fields=duration_ms%2Cheight%2Cmedia_key%2Cpreview_image_url%2Ctype%2Curl%2Cwidth%2Cpublic_metrics&poll.fields=duration_minutes%2Cend_datetime%2Cid%2Coptions%2Cvoting_status&place.fields=contained_within%2Ccountry%2Ccountry_code%2Cfull_name%2Cgeo%2Cid%2Cname%2Cplace_type&max_results=500&query=retweets_of%3ATerry81987010&start_time=2020-03-09T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00&end_time=2020-04-24T00%3A00%3A00%2B00%3A00',
   'version': '2.0.8',
   'retrieved_at': '2021-05-17T17:13:17+00:00'}}]
```

**What I need:**  I have to import the JSON file into the Pandas dataframe in a way that there would be a separate column for each field (i.e., completely flatten the nested lists). For example, instead of just one column for `referenced_tweets` which includes `type`, `id`, etc., there should be separate columns for each of them.

Here is my code:

```
retweets = []
for line in open('Data/usersRetweetsFlatten_sample.json', 'r'):
    retweets.append(json.loads(line))

df_retweets = json_normalize(
    retweets, 
    record_path=['referenced_tweets'], 
    meta_prefix=".", 
    meta= ["text", "created_at", "author_id", "conversation_id", "id"], 
    errors='ignore'
)

df_retweets[['author.username', 'type', 'id', '.id', 'referenced_tweets']].head()
```

**PROBLEM:** When I run the last line of code (`df_retweets.head()`), I don't know why the values of `id` and `type` columns don't match the corresponding values of type and id in the `referenced_tweets` column. For example, the value of the column `type` is always `retweeted` while the type in the referenced_tweets column is `replied_to`!!!! Please see the attached screenshot of the resulting dataframe.

[image]

Comment: Please can you post a valid json that we can copy-paste?

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean by valid json? I copy-pasted the first 3 lines of my json files because the whole json was too large. Also, all lines have similar structure.

Comment: I mean we can't read the json as-is using `json.loads`. Maybe just include the contents of `retweets[:2]` as a sample.

Comment: @not_speshal: also, I used the flattened version of the original json file (the original file was a json response from the Twitter API. I used the `twarc2 flatten originalFile.jsonl flattenFile.json` command. Hope I was clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is as expected and in line with the structure of your json, which is quite convoluted (multiple levels).

The "type" column is deriving it's values from the one level.

```
>>> retweets[0]["referenced_tweets"][0]["type"]
"retweeted"
```

Whilst the "referenced_tweets" column is coming from a more nested (i.e., deeper) level:

```
>>> retweets[0]["referenced_tweets"][0]["referenced_tweets"][0]["type"]
'replied_to'
```

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. Do you know how I can access the value of the `type` in the deeper level (e.g., `replied_to` in our example)? I mean how can I retrieve it in the resulting dataframe? (I want the column 'type' shows the type value that is in the column `referenced_tweets`.